# Tkinter VideoPlayer Library to Play a Video: TypeError: init() got multiple values for argument 'scaled'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-label

I am using it to create a windows app interface. I would like a video to play in the interface and not have another window pop up that plays the video. I have discovered a library called Tkinter VideoPlayer which is specifically used to play a video on a label. However, when I run the code with the existing code I have, I get the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'scaled'" .
```

I understand that the "scaled" variable is getting different values at the same time which is the reason why the code is not running. However, I am not sure how to fix this. I will include my code and the Github repository link.
Github link: https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkVideoPlayer/blob/master/tkVideoPlayer/tkvideoplayer.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkVideoPlayer import TkinterVideo


HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 800



root = tk.Tk()

#Canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

#Background Picture
background_img = tk.PhotoImage(file = "GundamNarrative2.png")
background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_img)
background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

#Background
background = tk.Frame(root, bg = "blue")
background.place(relx=.5, rely=.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor="n")

# Buttons
record_button = tk.Button(background, text = "Record", bg = "green")
record_button.place(relx = 0, rely = .5, relwidth = 0.15, relheight = .5)

skeleton_button = tk.Button(background, text = "Skeleton", bg = "red")
skeleton_button.place(relx = .4, rely = .5, relwidth = 0.15, relheight = .5)

frame_button = tk.Button(background, text = "Frame", bg = "yellow")
frame_button.place(relx = .85, rely = .5, relwidth = 0.15, relheight = .5)

#Label
video_label = tk.Label(background, text = "Enter video name below")
video_label.place(relx = 0.4, rely=0, relwidth=.25, relheight=.15)

#Entry Area
entry = tk.Entry(background, bg = 'gray')
entry.place(relx = 0.4, rely=.15, relwidth=.25, relheight=.35)

#Bottom Frame
bottom_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg = "blue", bd=10)
bottom_frame.place(relx = .5, rely=0.25, relwidth=.75, relheight=.65, anchor = "n")

#Screen
screen = tk.Label(bottom_frame, text = "I want video to play here", bg = "gray")
screen.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

#Error in line below
videoplayer = TkinterVideo(screen, scaled=True, pre_load=False)
videoplayer.load("C:\\Users\\jcoli\\PycharmProjects\\SwimCodeProject\\PoseVideos\\Jordan.mov")
videoplayer.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

videoplayer.play()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The problem is that you didn't specify `master=screen`.  The first parameter the TkinterVideo takes is scaled. So you need to explicitly set `master=screen` in TkinterVideo. Eg: `TkinterVideo(master=screen, scaled=True, pre_load=False)`. Btw default scaled option is True and the pre_load is False so there isn't a need to set it explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run setup.py for tKinterVideoPlayer. However, you DO NEED "scaled=" and "pre_load="

Answer (score 0):

In case you havent figured it out by now, I had the same error, it got fixed just by removing the name of the arguments when declaring your TkinterVideo :

videoplayer = TkinterVideo(screen,True,False)

should do the trick.

Comment: I unfortunately did not get the issue to solve. I have added the error message in the initial question. Maybe there is something wrong with the way I installed the TkinterVideo library. I was unable to "pip install" it to PyCharm. Therefore, I just copied and pasted the library code into a new file. Would that be the problem and if yes, how would I reinstall it the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any problem with the way you installed the library.

The problem is that you didn't specify `master=screen`. The first parameter the TkinterVideo takes is scaled. So you need to explicitly set `master=screen` in TkinterVideo. Eg: `TkinterVideo(master=screen, scaled=True, pre_load=False)`.
Btw, the default scaled option is True and the pre_load is False so there isn't a need to set it explicitly.

The `scaled` option will resize the video to the current screen size. If you set this to `False` you can specify the desired frame size using `videoplayer.set_size((300, 300))`. Note: it takes tuple as an argument